# Split a list in one cell into multiple cells in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a question.

So I have an excel document that has a list of instruction in ONE Cell. My question is how do I split the cell so that I can keep each numbered step into multiple steps. For instance:

| Steps (original) | Step (would Like it to be like this) |
| --- | --- |
| 1. open the software. 2. validate the form 3. Submit form number into system 4. close | 1. open the software |
|  | 2. Validate the form |
|  | 3. Submit form number into system |
|  | 4. close |

I would appreciate your help in this matter.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Office 365 you can do this with:

```
=LET(split,TEXTSPLIT(A1,,SEQUENCE(10,,0)&". ",1),
     counter,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(split))&". ",
counter&split)
```

[image]